# How to connect Grafana JSON datasource to AWS API Gateway

Tags: oauth-2.0, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, grafana, api-gateway

How can I configure the [JSON datasource](https://github.com/simPod/GrafanaJsonDatasource/) and Grafana to access an AWS API Gateway? I can secure the API and access it outside of Grafana, using either IAM or Cognito, but cannot figure out how to do the same from within the datasource. I've tried modifying grafana.ini with values from, for example, [here](https://www.cloudaeye.com/our-blog/grafana_cognito), but I cannot get it to work. If I can do it without spinning up a lambda authorizer that would be great.